# Column-values to rows-header without summarzie

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, rotation

I have this simple single table:

```
 Group      Name      
------------------------------
 Group A    Marco
 Group B    Sven  
 Group A    Adrian
 Group B    Tina
 Group B    Steffi
 Group C    Jil
 Group C    Bastian
```

and want to rotate is this way. For every value in column `Group` one new column:

```
Group A      Group B      Group C
------------------------------
Adrian       Steffi       Bastian
Marco        Sven         Jil
             Tina
```

Column "`Group A`", "`Group B`" and "`Group C`" are alphabetically sorted.

I tried it by "case when end" but the result was this:

```
Group A      Group B      Group C
------------------------------
Marco        null         null
Adrian       null         null
null         Steffi       null
null         Sven         null
null         Tina         null
null         null         Jil
null         null         Bastian
```

And it isn't sorted, either.

How can I achieve this? I need your help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: SELECT  
 (CASE when t.group = 'Group A' then t.user_name  END) [GruppeA],
 (CASE when t.group = 'Group B' then t.user_name  END) [GruppeB],
 (CASE when t.group = 'Group C' then t.user_name  END) [GruppeC]
FROM [dbo].groups t

Answer (score 1):

the static solution here : (but be carefully, in CTE a must be group having max count of names :))
(if you want sometheng more dynamically, write...)

```
;WITH CTE AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by [Group] ORDER BY [Group]) AS RN,[Group], Name 
             FROM YourTable)


SELECT x.Name AS GroupA, a.Name AS GroupB, z.Name AS GroupC
FROM CTE a
OUTER APPLY(SELECT Name FROM CTE b WHERE a.RN = b.RN AND b.[Group] = 'Group A') x
OUTER APPLY(SELECT Name FROM CTE c WHERE a.RN = c.RN AND c.[Group] = 'Group C') z
WHERE a.[Group] = 'Group B'
```

Okay you can also use this one : edited by your request( but its only for 3 groups...)

```
DECLARE @param_group1 varchar(50),
        @param_group2 varchar(50),
        @param_group3 varchar(50)

SET @param_group1 = 
(SELECT TOP 1 [Group] 
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY [Group] 
ORDER BY COUNT([Group]) DESC)

SET @param_group2 = 
(SELECT TOP 1 [Group] 
FROM YourTable
WHERE [Group] NOT IN (@param_group1)
GROUP BY [Group] 
ORDER BY COUNT([Group]) DESC)

SET @param_group3 = 
(SELECT TOP 1 [Group] 
FROM YourTable
WHERE [Group] NOT IN (@param_group1, @param_group2)
GROUP BY [Group] 
ORDER BY COUNT([Group]) DESC)

DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cmd = '
WITH CTE AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by [Group] ORDER BY [Group]) AS RN,[Group], Name 
             FROM YourTable)


SELECT x.Name AS ['+@param_group1+'], a.Name AS ['+@param_group2+'], z.Name AS ['+@param_group3+']
into ##tmp1
FROM CTE a
OUTER APPLY(SELECT Name FROM CTE b WHERE a.RN = b.RN AND b.[Group] = '''+@param_group2+''') x
OUTER APPLY(SELECT Name FROM CTE c WHERE a.RN = c.RN AND c.[Group] = '''+@param_group3+''') z
WHERE a.[Group] = '''+@param_group1+''''


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##tmp1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##tmp1
EXEC (@cmd)

SELECT [Group A],[Group B],[Group C]
FROM ##tmp1
```

Comment: Hi Metej,
yeah it worked! Big thanks! Now i only have to make it dynamically and to take care, that i detect the group having max count of names :-)